# Nextjs Modal Routing Opens Page Instead of Modal

Tags: reactjs, next.js, modal-dialog

I'm trying to implement an Instagram style modal routing in nextjs and I used the **with-route-as-modal** example but it's not working.
here is my implementation

Post file

```js
export const Post = ({name, id}) => {
 return (
      <div className={styles.captionContainer}>
         <Link href={`/[userName]/[postId]`} as={`/${name}/${id}`} shallow>
           <a>
              some text
           </a>
         </Link>
     </div>
 )
}
```

Modal route

```js
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import Modal from 'react-modal';
import {Post} from "path/to/post/component"

Modal.setAppElement('#__next')

export default function HomePage() {
    const router = useRouter()
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Home page</h1>
           <Post name="jone.doe" id="Xlmew20s"/>
  { // this post component has the link which
    //when clicked should show modal and not redirect to post page
  }
            <Modal
                isOpen={!!router.query.postId}
                onRequestClose={() => router.back()}
                contentLabel="Post modal"
               >
                <PostPage id={router.query.postId} name = {router.query.userName} />
            </Modal>
        </div >
    )
}
```

When the post link is clicked on the hompe page, instead of opening the modal, it opens the post page

Comment: Can you show us the code for the link you click on the homepage? Currently you're only showing the modal code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In Next.js How Can I Create a "Modal Link" (ie. Link That Changes URL and Adds a Component, But Doesn't Re-Render Whole Page)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66127164/in-next-js-how-can-i-create-a-modal-link-ie-link-that-changes-url-and-adds-a)